# PNAS two column not displaying

Tags: two-column, document-classes, pnas

I'm trying to use the PNAS two column class (pnastwo.cls). I include it by writing

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}
```

in my tex file. However, it still shows the text as one column. Why is that happening and how can I fix that?

The documentation (http://www.pnas.org/site/misc/PNASDOCS.PDF) doesn't seem to mention anything about such behavior

Comment: Please, add a MWE showing the issue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). The convention is not to add "thanks" comments to posts and, as egreg says, to add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\begin{article}...\end{article}` environment wrapper inside the body is needed for a twocolumn setup (strangely enough, however)

The document class can be found at [PNAS Author site](http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/latex.xhtml)

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}

\author{Miss Ann Elk\affil{1}{Ministry of Silly Walks}}
\title{On Brontosaurs}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{article}
\begin{materials}

\blindtext
\end{materials}
\end{article}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works but I'm also using the multicol package. When I include that via usepackge, I get the following error

 "! Output routine didn't use all of \box255"

Comment: @Opt: Well, your post did not reveal that you use `multicol` package. And in fact, you don't need it, I would say