# Table ref not displaying in PNAS format

Tags: two-column, document-classes, article, pnas

I'm using the PNAS two column style (pnastwo.cls). As per the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237200/pnas-two-column-not-displaying), I need to wrap my text in the article environment to have it actually display in two columns. However, this makes it so that references to my table don't appear. The caption sometimes doesn't appear either. Below is my code

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{article}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|}
  \hline
  testing \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{TESTING}
  \label{test}
\end{table}
Table~\ref{test}
\end{article}
\end{document}
```

and the output is

[image: pdf output]

As you can see, no reference to the table # and the caption doesn't appear either. If I remove the article environment, then the table # appears but the caption still doesn't.

Edit: As suggested by egreg below, moving the table out of the article environment makes the table # appear. The caption still doesn't though.

Comment: IIRC, tables should go after `\end{article}`.

Comment: Ok, that makes the table # appear but the caption still doesn't

Comment: The caption *must* go above the tabular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tables and figures must go after `\end{article}`. In both cases the caption must precede the object.

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{article}

Table~\ref{test}

\end{article}

\begin{table}
  \caption{TESTING}
  \label{test}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \hline
  testing & testing & testing \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>I'm very sorry for you being forced to use such a horrible document class: horrible for how it's written and for the output it produces.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

All floats must be after `\end{article}`, using the starred form if `two-column` mode is used.

This is clearly stated in the instruction manual:

[image]

```
\documentclass[final]{pnastwo}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{article}

In Table~\ref{test} we see

\end{article}
  \begin{table*}
    \caption{TESTING}
    \label{test}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
      \hline
      testing \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I omit a screen shot